# How to make sampling ignorable in Bayesian model with random (unequal) sampling probabilities?

Tags: probability, bayesian, sampling, survey-sampling, survey-weights

Suppose you sample N people with unequal probabilities from some superpopulation. Your sample contains W_sample the probability with which the person was sampled from the superpopulation and their outcome Y. For our purposes, let's assume W in the superpopulation is a draw from a dirichlet distribution, so W is a probability distribution while W_sample is not and need not sum to 1.

When confronted with unequal sample selection probabilities, Bayesians usually advise to condition on the variables generating the sampling weight. This makes sense as it renders the sampling design ignorable. However, it isn't clear what this would mean in this case - what should be conditioned on?